# Ubuntu - VirtualBox instllation issues

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm new to linux. I'm trying to install VirtualBox in my Ubuntu 12.04 but while installing from terminal the installation stopped with the below error.

```
http://pastebin.com/6d3Ux9qG
```

So I tried to install it from Ubuntu Software center, but it tells me that it got corrupted and run  apt-get install -f in the terminal.

```
http://pastebin.com/G43gHBaa
```

"This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  python-minimal python2.7-minimal (due to python-minimal)"

When I did that it broken my entire system. I reinstalled it from scratch and trying again to install VirtualBox but still the same issue. How can I repair this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it the wrong way.

First of all, it appears you attempt to install VirtualBox for i386 architecture, while your Ubuntu is amd64. Use amd64, this will prevent multiarch issues.

Then, use the Oracle repository to get the debian package and properly install VirtualBox with all the dependencies automatically solved :

In `/etc/apt/sources.list`, add `deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian precise contrib`. Then, do `wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -`. Finally, do `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.2`

Before doing this, do not forget to remove your half-installed package using `dpkg -r virtualbox-4.2:i386`.

Comment: yes,,now everything great...thank you so much..but im not sure how it is amd64 while I'm using Intel core i3..how to check this...anyway dpkg --print-architecture shows its amd64